# Python Regex - Pattern Matching

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I am looking for a way to regex unneeded information in a txt file.
The .txt file is constantly changing because it is being generated with a paramiko script that pulls specific data from a network device.

The file contains the following:

```
*Flags: X - disabled, R - running 
 0  R name="" mtu= l2mtu= mac-address= 
      arp=enabled interface-type= mode=station 
      ssid="" frequency= band=5ghz-a/n 
      channel-width=20/40mhz-XX secondary-frequency="" scan-list=5000-5900 
      wireless-protocol= vlan-mode=no-tag vlan-id=1 wds-mode= 
      wds-default-bridge=none wds-ignore-ssid=no bridge-mode= 
      default-authentication= default-forwarding= default-ap-tx-limit= 
      default-client-tx-limit= hide-ssid= security-profile= 
      compression=*
```

The specific part I am interested in is the **scan-list=xxxx-xxxx**

I accomplished this at first using linux and calling a .sh script with subprocess that would grep the required part, unfortunately, now I have to implement it on a windows system and do not have access to grep.

The code I currently have is able to return scan-list but also returns random brackets, here is the code and output:

**Code:**

```
import re
import string

file = open('test.txt', 'r')

for lines in file:
    matches = re.match('..........\d\d\d\d.\d\d\d\d', lines)
    print(matches)

**Output:**

    []
    []
    []
    []
    []
    []
    []
    []
    ['scan-list=5000-5900']
    []
    []
    []
    []
    []
    []
    []
    []
    []
    []
    []
    []
    []
```

This is all great but I cannot use this output as input for another function due to the brackets.

I have tried the .strip() but get stuck with a *TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object* presumably because the content is in a file and not a specified string.

I have also tried calling re.sub using lambda but this seems to only return the brackets and not the scan-list.

Eventually to try and bypass the problem I attempted to write the output to a secondary temporary file and do another regex with re .sub / re .replace to remove the brackets, but this ended with the regex once again keeping all the brackets but removing the scan-list part.

After all of this failed, I decided to go back and look at the regex itself, even doing a pattern match for "scan-list\d\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d" seemed to fail and remove everything except the brackets.

I am now wondering if these brackets are cursed and I will just have to resort to WSL.
Is there perhaps an easier way to go about this or a different library I can check out and try?

This is probably a very simple problem, and I believe my regex string might be terrible or completely incorrect.

Comment: I assume `(scan-list=\d+-\d+)` should suffice

Comment: Unfortunately not Steve, it still throws out random brackets. Not really sure where these brackets even come from, the original file does not have brackets.

Comment: Adding to steve's answer, let the string variable be `x`, then, `y = re.findall(r'scan-list=\d+-\d+',x)` gives you output: `['scan-list=5000-5900']`

Comment: Also should note that you are using [re.match](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match) which starts the matching from the beginning of the string.

Comment: oof sorry forgot to change .match() before posting, was actually using .findall() in the beginning. 
Thanks a mil, I'll try this solution as well.

Comment: `re.findall` would be why you were getting the `[]` then, zero matches is just an empty list. You could check `matches` with an if statement before printing

Comment: I cannot reproduce the described behaviour and I have difficulty extracting an actual **question** here. Please read [ask] and [mre] and make sure that, if someone else **copies and pastes your code, without changing anything**, it will do **exactly** what you describe. This includes hard-coding the text input into the program. Please also [try to understand](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) the problem and use appropriate terminology: "returns random brackets" does not make any sense.

Comment: Finally, try to think carefully about the logic of the program. There is a loop that will consider each line of the input with a regex, right? Well, **what should happen** if there is nothing on that line which matches the regex? Should a `print` happen at all? If it should, what should get displayed? Next, what do you expect `re.match` to do when the input does not match the regex? What do you expect `re.findall` to do? What do you expect `re.search` to do? If you are not sure, did you [**read the documentation**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)?

Comment: Thanks @KarlKnechtel, revisiting the question afterwards I see what you mean with the loop considering all lines within the file. 
As for the brackets, I do not know how else you would like me to term them when I had no idea where they came from. 
Personally I feel the question was quite straight forward with a decent explanation, apologies that it did not meet your standards.

Comment: First off, `return` has a specific meaning that has nothing to do with printing. It's also not hard to come up with better words than "random"; how about "unexpected"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re
import string

file = open('test.txt', 'r')

for lines in file:
    matches = re.search('scan-list=\d{4}-\d{4}', lines)
    if matches != None:
      print(matches.group())

# Outputs all occurrences line by line.
```

Explanation:

- You need to use re.search instead of re.match for matching strings that are not at the beginning of the line.
- When a line does not contain the desired string, re.search returns None, so we avoid printing those.
- matches.group() / matches.group(0) will return the first subgroup, which is the entire match.
- Your regex was just good.

Comment: The edit which adds explanation is being [discussed on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/420322/what-was-wrong-with-this-suggested-edit)